# Django - How to Get ID before ensuring form is valid

Tags: python, django

I am facing an issue where I have multiple forms on one page. What I am trying to do is update an item using an update form.

The issue is I am unable to display the most current data that is in DB in the template.

When I request the pk, it comes from a different model that is not related to this one. I need to get the ID before ensuring that the form is valid so I can filter and get the correct item based on the ID in order to display the data that I need.

**models.py**

```
class DevIssues(models.Model):
    ISSUE_CODE = [
        ('BUG', 'Bug'),
        ('BACKLOG', 'Backlog'),
        ('REQUEST', 'Request'),
        ('TODO', 'To-Do'),
    ]
    ISSUE_STATUS = [
        ('NEW', 'New'),
        ('WIP', 'In Progress'),
        ('Complete', 'Complete'),
    ]
    project = models.ForeignKey(DevProjects, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='issue')
    issue = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    issue_desc = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    issue_code = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=ISSUE_CODE, null=True, blank=True)
    issue_status = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=ISSUE_STATUS, default='New')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**forms.py**

```
class AddProjectIssues(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DevIssues
        fields= ["issue", "issue_desc", "issue_code"]
        labels = {
            'issue': 'Issue',
            'issue_desc': 'Issue Description',
            'issue_code': 'Issue Code',
        }


class UpdateProjectIssues(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DevIssues
        fields= ["issue_status"]
```

**views.py**

```
issue_project = get_object_or_404(DevProjects, pk=pk)
    issues = DevIssues.objects.filter(project=issue_project).order_by('-created_at')
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'addissue' in request.POST:
            issue_form = AddProjectIssues(request.POST or None)
            if issue_form.is_valid():
                content = request.POST.get('issue')
                content2 = request.POST.get('issue_desc')
                content3 = request.POST.get('issue_code')
                issues = DevIssues.objects.create(issue=content, issue_desc=content2, issue_code=content3, project=project, created_by=request.user)
                issues.save()
                return redirect("/projects")

    else:
        issue_form = AddProjectIssues()


    content1 = DevIssues.objects.filter(id= **here**).first() #here I need to get ID before so I can filter and get the correct data to be displayed.
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'updateissue' in request.POST:
            update_issue_form = UpdateProjectIssues(request.POST, instance=content1)
            if update_issue_form.is_valid():
                content = request.POST.get('issue_status')
                content2 = request.POST.get('updateissue')
                notes = DevIssues.objects.filter(id=content2).update(issue_status=content)
                return redirect('/projects')

    else:
        update_issue_form = UpdateProjectIssues(instance=content1)
```

Again, the PK that I am getting through the request for DevProjects as this Issue form is based on a DevProject.

**How can I get the ID of an item, without requesting the PK via URL in order to filter and get the correct data to display? Any and all help is appreciated.**

Comment: you most likely want to use some sort of dynamic forms django plugin or use some js magic, try this library for starters: https://pypi.org/project/django-dynamic-forms/

Comment: @SLDem I am using Django Crispy Forms. Should I try something other than that?

Comment: yes try ddf, here is the docs: https://django-dynamic-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fetch the Urls via Ajax and not by Django URL dispatcher. As per my understanding you have multiple forms and after submitting the 1st form you want to get its pk and by which you want to fill the 2nd form and store the primary key in the another model table. Please use axios to call the Urls.

You can reply to this message to convey anything.

Comment: Hello! I am sorry if I was not clear enough. What happens is say somebody will create a “Project” within that project is the issue form. When a user creates an issue (within the project) I get the projects PK from the url to assign the project to that issue. I am able to update the issue no problem. What I need to do is somehow get the url to the existing issue in order to get the data to display correctly. I am able to get the data using a query set, but when I use crispy forms (to update one field) it is not getting the most current data from the database. I need to display the current data.